# How to deserialize a JSON object containing special characters using [FromBody] in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core controller that takes an object as input using the [FromBody] attribute. When I send a JSON object containing special characters, such as {"name": "ç"}, I get the following error:

*The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $.name | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 15.*

Project is in dotnet 7.

Here is my controller code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace JsonError.Controllers
{
    public class Example
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class ExampleController : ControllerBase
    {

        [HttpPost(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public IActionResult Get([FromBody] Example example)
        {
            return Ok(example);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my program.cs code:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

The only possible way to reproduce the error is using the following CURL command:
`curl -X POST http://localhost:5000/example -H 'Content-Type: application/json;' -d '{"name": "ç"}'`

Error:

```
threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    InnerException: {"Unable to translate bytes [E7] at index 1 from specified code page to Unicode."}
    Message: "Cannot transcode invalid UTF-8 JSON text to UTF-16 string."
    Source: "System.Text.Json"
    StackTrace: "   at System.Text.Json.JsonReaderHelper.TranscodeHelper(ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8Unescaped)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.GetString()
   at JsonError.Controllers.CustomConverter.Read(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) in D:\Projects\JsonError\JsonError\Controllers\CustomConverter.cs:line 12"
    TargetSite: {System.String TranscodeHelper(System.ReadOnlySpan`1[System.Byte])}
```

How can I deserialize a JSON object containing special characters using [FromBody] in ASP.NET Core without getting this error?

Comment: I test your code find it works, no error, like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QQoo.png

Comment: Try to use escape sequences for special characters, such as "\u00E7" for the letter "ç".

Comment: @QingGuo the error only occour when you call it by the curl command.

Answer (score 2):

That's an error in your console. It doesn't use Unicode. Instead it uses some codepage where the character ç is encoded as `0xE7` (decimal: 231).

As the error indicates, that is invalid UTF-8. In UTF-8, the code point 231 must be [encoded using two bytes](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/E7/index.htm): `0xC3`, `0xA7`.

Use a terminal that understand Unicode.

Comment: Or maybe specify the encoding in your content-type, but I'd go with using an Unicode-capable terminal.

Answer (score -1):

> '{"name": "ç"}'

change it  to  `"{\"name\": \"ç\"}"`

Try the below code :

```
curl -X POST https://localhost:7015/Example -H "Content-type:application/json" -d "{\"name\": \"ç\"}"
```

result:

[image]

Comment: I don't believe that's the problem at all. The OP doesn't need to escape the double-quotes, because they've put it all in single-quotes. I believe this is about the encoding of the character with a cedilla - not quote escaping.

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet , my style is use double-quotes, he can use  single-quotes too, I want to suggest to try to add "\" . Do you try the code? Do you try to reproduce the problem ?

Comment: I didn't try either approach, because I believe this is fundamentally about the OP's console, as per CodeCaster's answer. Did *you* try the OP's command line and reproduce the problem, then fix it by using escape sequences? I strongly suspect that if you try the OP's command line, you'll see that works on your system too... (In which case, there's no evidence that changing the quoting style fixes the problem at all.)